# Como passar um valor de um dicionário (que está dentro de outro dicionário) para uma Label? Swift 3

Tags: json, ios, swift, alamofire

Eu tenho um banco de dados mais ou menos assim:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Mike",
      "informations": [
        {
          "id": 474,
          "text": "My son",
          "reference": "www.google.com",
        }
      ]
    }
```

Eu estou procurando por esses dados através do Alamofire. Gostaria de criar uma View, inserir uma Label e, nesta Label, aparecer o texto do atributo "text" e em outra Label, o nome do atributo "name" e outra com o valor "referência". Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce precisa cast seus elementos de Any para o tipo do seu elemento:
Tenta da seguinte forma, se voce tiver problema parsing o seu dicionário numa só condicional, melhor break-down o código abaixo:

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["status": "OK", "data": [["id": 1, "name": "Mike", "informations": [[ "id": 474, "text": "My son", "reference": "www.google.com" ]]]]]

if let status = dict["status"] as? String, status == "OK",
    let data = dict["data"] as? [[String: Any]],
    let dataDict = data.first,
    let id = dataDict["id"] as? Int,
    let name = dataDict["name"] as? String,
    let info = dataDict["informations"] as? [[String: Any]],
    let infoDict = info.first,
    let infoID = infoDict["id"] as? Int,
    let text = infoDict["text"] as? String,
    let reference = infoDict["reference"] as? String {
    print(id)     // ""1\n"
    print(name)   // "Mike\n"
    print(infoID) // "474\n"
    print(text)   // "My son\n"
}
```

Comment: Mas o banco em questão eu recupero como uma API. Tem alguma diferença? E como ficaria caso houvesse mais de um dicionário dentro do atributo "informations"?

Comment: Voce perguntou como acessar um dicionario dentro do outro, o que eu já respondi. Se quiser saber como converter os seus dados (JSON string - resposta do servidor) para Dicionário `[String: Any]`, você precisa converter a Data (String UTF8) pra dicionario usando `NSJSONSerialization` JSONObject from data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39462969/2303865

Comment: Obrigado Leo, vou testar o que me passou! :D